# How do you go about comparing two servers in order to figure out how many of one, you could replace with a newer one?

Tags: performance, benchmark

How do you go about comparing two servers in order to figure out how many of one, you could replace with a newer one?

In particular, I have the following

Old server: ProLiant BL460c G6 (1.86 GHz, Intel Xeon E5502)
New server: ProLiant BL460c Gen9 (1.80 GHz, Intel Xeon E5-2630L v3)

I can go onto CPU benchmarking website and compare the CPUs http://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=1238&cmp%5B%5D=2818  (for a direct comparison) 
https://www.spec.org/cgi-bin/osgresults (for benchnmark)

However, I am not sure how to be able to say that my G6s can be replaced by x G9s? How do I factor in core count and memory? Anyone know a smart way of doing this, or any other metrics to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before doing any sort of benchmark you should do an analysis of the most common workloads to be run on the servers.  Determine if they are CPU, Memory, I/O(disk) or I/O(network) bound.  This can be done through a variety of methods.  Once you understand these requirements look for specific benchmarks that test these aspects of system performance.  The [iozone](http://www.iozone.org) benchmark is used to test file systems, [stream](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/) can be used to test memory bandwidth, and there are a variety of others.

For pure CPU workload the [High-Performance Linpack(HPL)](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/hpl/) is widely used to test pure floating point operations per second(FLOPS).  For single node tests any [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) workload that uses over 75% of the memory on the system can be used to get a pretty good idea of CPU performance